# Error 3241 when restore back up in sql server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012

when i was restore database in sql server 2012 this error happend

> Msg 3241, Level 16, State 0, Line 3
>   The media family on device 'D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\Test.bak' is incorrectly formed. SQL Server cannot process this media family.
>   Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   RESTORE HEADERONLY is terminating abnormally.

what should i do?

Answer (score 1):

What version of SQL Server did you take this backup from?  Usually you get this error when you are trying to restore a backup taken on a higher version of SQL Server (Such as 2012) onto a lower version (Such as 2008 R2).

If that is the case, you will need to script out your database and recreate it on the new server rather than simply backing up and restoring.

If the file has not come from a newer version of SQL server than the one you are trying to restore it onto, it is possible that the file has simply been corrupted, at which point you should try to take a new backup if possible.  If you are attempting to restore across the network, you should also check permissions to make sure that this is not causing your issue too.